D'alembertian operator in classical EM
From manipulating a bit the electric field's expression:
$$\vec{E}=-\vec{\nabla}\phi-\frac{\partial \vec{A}}{\partial t}$$
where $\phi$ is the electric potential and $\vec{A}$ is the magnetic vector potential, I get an equation that's very similar to Poisson's equation, but the operator is not a Laplacian but a D'Alembertian. Taking divergences in both sides:
$$\vec{\nabla}\cdot \vec{E}=-\nabla^2 \phi -\frac{\partial}{\partial t}(\vec{\nabla}\cdot \vec{A})$$
The left hand side, according to Maxwell's first law, can be written in terms of a charge density:
$$\frac{\rho}{\varepsilon_0}=-\nabla^2\phi -\frac{\partial}{\partial t}(\vec{\nabla}\cdot \vec{A})$$
Now, the last term in the right hand side depends on the gauge we choose. If we chose Coulomb's gauge ($\vec{\nabla}\cdot \vec{A}=0$), then we get an ordinary Poisson equation:
$$\nabla^2 \phi = -\frac{\rho}{\varepsilon_0}$$
Nonetheless, if we choose to adopt the Lorentz gauge ($\vec{\nabla}\cdot \vec{A}+\frac{1}{c^2}\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial t}=0$):
$$\nabla^2\phi -\frac{1}{c^2}\frac{\partial^2\phi}{\partial t^2}=-\frac{\rho}{\varepsilon_0}$$
The operator on the left is easily recognised as a D'Alembertian operator in the Minkowski metric:
$$\boxed{\square\phi=-\frac{\rho}{\varepsilon_0}}$$
What are the implications of this? Why do we get a D'Alembertian in an equation which we have not imposed to be relativistic?

Maxwell's system of equations is relativistic.

The Lorenz (no "t") gauge is relativistic, it has all 4 (3+1) derivatives of the 4-vector $A, \phi$. The Coulomb gauge is not relativistic, and neither is Poisson's equation.
